# How I get each URL text value which scrape I Only get last URL value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am new to Python. by this code I only last URL values but I want each URL scrape content.

```
contents = []
with open('c:\\users\\thegl\\documents\\datab.csv','r') as csvf: # Open file in read mode
    urls = csv.reader(csvf)
    for url in urls:
        contents.append(url) # Add each url to list contents

for url in contents:  # Parse through each url in the list.
    page = urlopen(url[0]).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
for List in soup.find_all('ol',class_='breadcrumb'):
    for listext in List.find_all('li'):
        print(listext.text)
```

> file datab.csv contain following ULS:
> https://www.dumpstool.com/1Y0-371-exam.html
> https://www.dumpstool.com/TK0-201-exam.html
> https://www.dumpstool.com/C9510-401-exam.html

Answer (score 0):

You should indent the last `for` so it is executed for each url.

```py
contents = []
with open('c:\\users\\thegl\\documents\\datab.csv','r') as csvf: # Open file in read mode
    urls = csv.reader(csvf)
    for url in urls:
        contents.append(url) # Add each url to list contents

for url in contents:  # Parse through each url in the list.
    page = urlopen(url[0]).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    for List in soup.find_all('ol',class_='breadcrumb'):
        for listext in List.find_all('li'):
            print(listext.text)
```

Comment: It's still not working by indent the last for.

Comment: What is the output you get ? What output do you expect ? Do you have any error ?

Comment: The output is the same as before the last URL in file datab.csv shows the result of scraped content but i want each URL in the file to show breadcrumb text.

Comment: Try to print `contents` after the `with` code block. And `url[0]` before the `urlopen`. To see if they are what they should.

Comment: `contents = []
with open('c:\\users\\thegl\\documents\\date.csv','r') as csvf: # Open file in read mode
    urls = csv.reader(csvf)
    for url in urls:
        contents.append(url) # Add each url to list contents
        print(url)

for url in contents:  # Parse through each url in the list.
    page = urlopen(url[0]).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
for List in soup.find_all('ol',class_='breadcrumb'):
  for listext in List.find_all('li'):
    print(listext.text)` givie me this result.

Comment: ['https://www.dumpstool.com/1Y0-371-exam.html']
['https://www.dumpstool.com/TK0-201-exam.html']
['https://www.dumpstool.com/C9510-401-exam.html']
['https://www.dumpstool.com/2V0-620-exam.html']
['https://www.dumpstool.com/C_GRCAC_10-exam.html']
['https://www.dumpstool.com/77-888-exam.html']
['https://www.dumpstool.com/C_ARCON_2005-exam.html']
['https://www.dumpstool.com/IIA-ACCA-exam.html']
Home
IIA
CIA Challenge Exam

 IIA-ACCA - ACCA CIA Challenge Exam 
[Finished in 13.0s]  This show me the last URL breadcrumb result not all.

Comment: ![screenshot](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-4kuf0DJe2FU/YG6fR-K6qhI/AAAAAAAABeA/DyiXBSXUY7YJorQXgVLS7fX5yHuoHVFBgCLcBGAsYHQ/s16000/imppy.PNG)

Comment: Please edit your question when adding new information. Seeing your screenshot the line 15 is not properly indented it should be indented. Also it is bad practice (and can lead to error) to mix tabs with space when indenting. Please indent line 15 and indent with only spaces or only tabs.